# sublime text 2 plugin for inline autocomplete for javascript core functions

Tags: sublimetext

Is there a pluging for Sublime Text 2 that shows like a list of possible core/fundamental functions attached with lets say array.

So if i type 
`var a = []; & then  a.` it start showing stuff like `slice, join, push...`

basically like how google chrome does. Google chrome has an awesome auto complete for Css and Javascript. Just start writing in console or css part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a great plugin called [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel). It does exactly what you want.

You can install it via [PackageControl](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control) and it does provide code completion not only for JavaScript but also for many other languages: PHP, Python, RHTML, JavaScript, Smarty, Mason, Node.js, XBL, Tcl, HTML, HTML5, TemplateToolkit, XUL, Django, Perl, Ruby, Python3

Comment: I can't get javascript autocompletion works the same way as Chrome Dev Tool does for example. I just get suggestions about things I've typed in before.